# Importing .csv and converting to dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, r, date, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file with date information in the format MMM-YY (e.g., Jan-92). My ultimate goal is to have the information in a date format in SQL. The format doesn't matter that much to me, but I was thinking something like dd-mm-yy (e.g., 16-01-92). I've tried a lot and looked around the forum, but can't figure it out.

Right now, I am loading the data from the CSV into a column "period_month" as a VARCHAR field.

Then, my conversion code looks like

```
UPDATE PERIODS 
SET period_month = DATE(str_to_date(period_month,'%M-%Y'));
```

I end up with a field of VARCHAR type in the format yyyy-mm-dd, with the dd field set to '00'. (e.g., 1992-01-00)

I really just want this to be in a date format that I can export to another program like R for analysis.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What should the day be when the date string doesn't specify one?

Comment: Read your csv file using R, then convert to date: `lubridate::dmy(paste0("1-","Jan-92"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
UPDATE PERIODS 
SET period_month =DATE(str_to_date('Jan-92','%M-%Y')+1)
```

or

```
UPDATE PERIODS 
SET period_month =DATE(str_to_date('period_month','%M-%Y')+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

use date_format function of mysql query